# control the number of times a php class is loaded with certain parameters

Tags: php

I have a php class that connects to certain devices via ssh. 
I would like to add logic to control the number of connections, per device. 
This is what my class constructor looks like:

```
public function __construct($hostname, $password, $username = "", $timeout = 10) 
    {
        set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . '/var/www/phpseclib');
        include_once('Net/SSH2.php');
        $this->_hostname = $hostname;
        $this->_password = $password;
        $this->_username = $username;

    } // __construct
```

I've read some other posts like : [How to save a variable at application level in php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302495/how-to-save-a-variable-at-application-level-in-php)

and I guess I just want to confirm the following:

1. I think database would be better than file because of scenarios where multiple sessions are trying to write / update the class counter.
2. the class contructor and destructors are the best / only place to add this type of logic.

The only thing is that currently, I don't have a database associated with my app - so I hate to add this "dependency" but it does seem like the best way to go.  If you have any comments / suggestions, please let me know.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**

One additional question that comes up with adding the logic in my constructor is the following...
Assuming I have the following logic (pseudocode)

```
  public function __construct($hostname) 
  {
     if (!  ok_to_connect($hostname)  )
     {
         exit;
     }
  }

  public function ok_to_connect($hostname)
  {
    $filelist = glob($counterslocation.$hostname.'*.tmp');

    if ( count($filelist)  < 4) {
        $handle = fopen($counterslocation.$hostname.rand(1,4).".tmp", "r");
        return true;
    }       
    else {
        return false;
    }
   }
```

In the case where i already have 4 active connections, wouldn't calling exit() in my constructor still envoke the destructor?  This means that the destructor will try to delete one of the temp files, even though the ok_to_connect() function didn't actually create a file.  I guess i can have the ok_to_connect() method set a public variable in the class, and have the destructor check this before deleting any files.
Is this the best way to go?

Comment: regarding 1.) for each connection you could create a file with a random filename in a common directory. This way you don't have problems with write/update. Of course this might be problematic if you have a very big number of connections.

Comment: I don't think this is StackOverflow material; this shouldn't have been moved as it's no concrete problem.

Comment: Is this the kind of problem for which an Observer would be a good solution?

Comment: @yoshi, if i create with a random file name, how do i keep track of how many connections I have? sorry, can you clarify?  Thank you.

Comment: @dot just count the number of files inside the directory. ;) Of course `__destruct` would need to remove the file associated with that particular connection.

Comment: @yoshi. thanks.  do you want to add your comments as an answer?

Comment: @dot If you're actually considering it as an answer, I will add it as one. Wasn't sure though. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of keeping count in a single file, you could,

- on `__construct` create a file in a common directory,
- and on `__destruct` remove that file.

This way you won't have problems with simultaneous write operations. And the total number of files would show the number of open connections.

Comment: @dot Personally I would split `ok_to_connect` into two methods. As a method/function should do exactly one thing. The current one is doing two. Checking if it's `ok_to_connect`, and if so, creating the tmp file. I think you should have a second method `create_connection_file` which you call from the constructor, in case `ok_to_connect` returns true.

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 solutions here.

1- Using an in memory cache like APC. Of course you will loose the counter if your server restart but you'll probably going to loose the ssh connection too.
To deal with concurrency problem with APC you can take a look to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5288722/php-stats-object-stored-in-memory-concurrent-updates-data-loss)

```
if(!apc_exists($this->_hostname)) {
    apc_store($this->_hostname,1);
} else {
    apc_inc($this->_hostname);
}
```

2- Using a database :
   A very light database like sqlite included in php will provide persistance to the counter contrary to the in memory solution.

The database solution is more robust but slower. In case of reboot , you also need to clean all the counters because of the persistance.

You just have to know how critic are your data to choose the good solution.